# Lucene not indexing table

Tags: hibernate, indexing, lucene, hibernate-search

I hope someone can help me, I have 10 tables indexed with lucene, one table does not get indexed and I cant figure out why. 
My setup is Glassfish 3.1.2 with hibernate 4.2.3.
I'm using jpa in stateless beans, the entity is annotated with @Indexed and @Field. all other tables get indexed just one won't index and i'm not getting any errors in the log file.

Has anyone run into the same problem ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use a program called Luke (https://code.google.com/p/luke/), so you could check your index and see, if these tables are really indexed or not?

If yes, and all 9 tables are indexed, but not last - you need to check your configuration, find the difference in classes